# Christmas Markets in Trentino-Alto Adige

Tags: italy, seasonal

I want to visit some Christmas Markets in Trentino-Alto Adige.

- Which one is the biggest (in terms of the number of cribs)?
- Which has the widest selection of food and wine?
- Which has the most original hand made goodies?

Comment: Hi Basak, you've been around on Travel.SE for a while now. Be aware that you're question treads very close to being a shopping recommendation, [which is not allowed as defined in the FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). 'Biggest' market, 'most amount of original items' can be answered objectively; however, 'best selection' of food and wine is slightly subjective. Perhaps you might want to rephrase that as 'widest selection', which can be answered objectively.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.christmasmarkets.com/Italy.html) can help you. It lists a lot of Christmas Markets in Italy. It seems that there are two big Christmas market near Trentino.

Arco Christmas Market

Trento Christmas Market

It is difficult to say which one of these two is bigger, but I think the following quote about the Trento Christmas Market will suit you:

> A real treat is the gastronomic event “Sapori del Mercatino”, which
>   involves 15 market booths, offering Trentino delicacies for
>   degustation.